# Is the 16th & 17th verse transposed in Philippians 1?

Tags: philippians

Philippians 1:14 (NKJV)

> 14 and most of the brethren in the  Lord, having become confident by my chains, are much  more bold to speak the word without fear.
>
> 15 Some indeed preach Christ even from envy and strife,  and some also from goodwill:
>
> 16 The ***former*** b preach  Christ from selfish ambition, not sincerely, supposing to  add affliction to my chains;
>
> 17 but the ***latter*** out of love,  knowing that I am appointed for the defense of the gospel.

Could verse 16 & 17 be transposed in the above texts, since the former could only be referring to verse 14 & the latter to verse 15, but then that creates a problem since the brethren that speak boldly without fear in verse 14 do not correspond with the (former) brethren in verse 16 & those in verse 15 that preach out of envy & strife do not correspond with the (latter) in verse 17

Comment: Why don't you think the former refers to verse 15a and the latter to 15b?

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking the question because you saw the transpositions in the other translations? They all make sense, regardless of the translation. Why some transposed the sentences seems like a better question. ie, NIV reads:  "It is true that some preach Christ out of envy and rivalry, but others out of goodwill. The latter do so out of love ...The former ...out of self ambition."

Answer (score 2):

The Greek actually just uses the plural article οἱ in both cases; "former" and "later" are inferred from context.  The old King James uses "the one" and "the other".

Verses 16 and 17 refer to the two parties in verse 15 - those who *preach Christ from envy and strife* and those who preach Christ *from goodwill*.  Consider John Chrysostom's commentary on verse 15 (4th century):

> *Some indeed preach Christ even of envy and strife, and some also of good will*
>
> And what this means is worth enquiry. Since Paul was under restraint,
>   many of the unbelievers, willing to stir up more vehemently the
>   persecution from the Emperor, themselves also preached Christ, in
>   order that the Emperor’s wrath might be increased at the spread of the
>   Gospel, and all his anger might fall on the head of Paul. From my
>   bonds then two lines of action have sprung. One party took great
>   courage thereat; the other, from hope to work my destruction, set
>   themselves to preach Christ; “some of them through envy,” that is,
>   envying my reputation and constancy, and from desire of my
>   destruction, and the spirit of strife, work with me; or that they
>   themselves may be esteemed, and from the expectation that they will
>   draw to themselves somewhat of my glory. “And some also of good will,”
>   that is, without hypocrisy, with all earnestness.
>
> *Homily II on the Epistle of St. Paul to the Philippians*